# How to select a few items from the list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a scenario like

```
 log=[None]*4
```

and then based on certain conditions i'm inserting a value at one of the None position in log list.
Suppose

```
log=[Begin,None,None,None]
```

Now i want to get only

```
log=[Begin]
```

and that too not using index as per my code whenever/wherever there is None it'll insert value
How to do this. I have tried list comprehension but i think 'not in' doesn't work in that.

```
wal=[log[i] for i not in [None]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a list of elements from `log` which are not `None`. You can get this list by issuing

```
 mylist = [x for x in log if x]
```

Or, if there could be values other than `None` in `log` which evaluate to `False` in a boolean context *and* you want these values in your new list:

```
 mylist = [x for x in log if x is not None]
```

Demo:

```
>>> log
[None, '', None, 1]
>>> [x for x in log if x]
[1]
>>> [x for x in log if x is not None]
['', 1]
```